# VIteJS Laravel, background-img in .css

Tags: php, css, laravel, port, vite

I'm struggling to use `background-image: url("/assets/back.png");` in laravel with vitejs.
On the web page, the image is going to be searched on port 5173 (the one of vite) and not on port 8000, the one of Laravel, so the image is not found.

My image is in `/public/assets/back.png`
And my css file in `/resources/css/app.css`

Do you have an idea of how to do it ?

Comment: My directory IS correct but the things is that the image is getting on the vite URL, note the one of Laravel. If I use style in HTML it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `@/resources/images/img.png` which should be converted as `/images/img.png` during dev process and `/assets/images/img.xwv31s.png` after prod build.

Comment: Link is dead. Leads to spam/scam now.

Comment: Website seems gone. Maybe this thread should help too : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/laravel-vite-setup-with-assets

Answer (score 0):

you can use the class **bg-[url('...')]** with the full url *http://yourdomain/assets/back.png*
if you use .blade.php
class="bg-[url('{{asset("/assets/back.png")}}')]"

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make a proxy to make it work:

```
server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/assets/.*': {
                target: 'http://localhost',
            }
        }
    }
```